# Implementation selection in Java sales class scenario

Tags: java, design-patterns, uml

Sales application scenario:

This application provides discounts to the customer based on various strategies:

For example :

```
customer total purchase amount is > 10000  -  discount calculation following Rule1

customer is a senior citizen - discount calculation following Rule2

customer is purchasing on Tuesday - discount calculation following Rule3

customer is purchasing on 1st of everymonth- discount calculation following Rule4

customer is purchasing on a  specific day (admin can provide this offer)- discount calculation following RuleX
```

If a senior citizen  is purchasing on Tuesday with an amount greater than 10000 , then ideally he should 
to get best eligible discount from the above scenarios.What is the design pattern we can use to address this?
Is it possible to use strategy pattern here? (here we need to use multiple RULE based calculation to decide which
one should be best for the user, but strategy support singleImplementation(diccount calculation) selection at runtime)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need for a design pattern at all.
What you need is a [flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) diagram, which covers all your different cases. Finally you have to implement those flow cases.

---

**FYI:**
A strategy pattern can be applied, if you need different implementation for a specific abstract type. For an example have a look at the concrete implementations of `java.util.List` which are implemented as a strategy pattern.

*The reason why you should not use a strategy pattern for your scenario is that you will never hava a finite number of different implementation in your sales application. Soon or later, this will end up with a unmaintainable strategy monster!*

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a design pattern for this ? As far as I'm concerned, I would simply test the eligibility of the customer to all offers and compare the discount of all offers that passed the test.

Some offers may be always more interesting than others, if that's the case you could test them prior to the others to save you some tests if the customer is eligible to a such offer.